# is it possible to use a variable value across multiple actions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have index and show method like below

```
def index
  @variable = SomeModel.includes(:some_other_model)
end

def show
  @variable = SomeModel.includes(:some_other_model).find_by!(id: params[:id])
end
```

so `SomeModel.includes(:some_other_model)` is common in both actions and i am doing join on some_other_model twice in index and show method

so i thought lets do before_action move it to a private method

```
  before_action :set_something, only: [:index, :update]

    def index
      @variable
    end

    def show
      @variable.find_by!(id: params[:id])
    end

      private

    def set_something
    @variable = SomeModel.includes(:some_other_model) if @variable.nil?
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
```

So my question is, is there any way i can store the @variable value when either index or show is called and when next time other action is called just use the same @variable value and not hit database again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way i can store the `@variable` value when either index or show is called and when next time other action is called just use the same `@variable` value and **not hit database again**?

No, there is no way. When the other action is called, it's a completely different instance of your controller class. And that instance variable from last time, it's long gone.

That aside, you should do what Sebastian suggests. It's a logical continuation of what you started (so that, at least, you don't hit the DB twice in *the same action*).

---

> We can't achieve that using class instance variables too?

Using class-level data, this is more achievable, but only if you have one web process (so that all requests are guaranteed to use the same class). As soon as you add another web worker, this stops working.

This question made me look at your code again, and I realized that this all is pointless/misguided. :)

```
 @variable = SomeModel.includes(:some_other_model)
```

This line does not hit database. So it doesn't make sense to try and memoize it. Saves nothing. THIS is what hits the database

```
  @variable = SomeModel.includes(:some_other_model).find_by!(id: params[:id])
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. So just curious, we cant achieve that using class instance variables too?

Comment: Nice. Thanks for your help.